# CocoaPod with static library dependencies

Tags: swift, dependencies, cocoapods

I'm currently trying to create a pod for the first time that contains several dependencies.

The pods I'm currently including in my pod are as follows

- FacebookCore
- FacebookLogin
- Fabric
- TwitterKit
- Google/SignIn
- LinkedinSwift

My `podspec` file looks like this

```
Pod::Spec.new do |s|

  s.platform     = :ios
  s.ios.deployment_target = '8.0'
  s.name         = "Socializin"
  s.version      = "0.0.1"
  s.summary      = "A short description of Socializin."
  s.requires_arc = true

  s.author       = {"MyName" => "MyMail"}
  s.homepage     = "http://EXAMPLE/Socializin"
  s.license      = { :type => "MIT", :file => "LICENSE" }
  s.source       = { :git => "", :tag => "#{s.version}"}

  s.framework    = "UIKit"
  s.dependency 'FacebookCore', '~> 0.2.0'
  s.dependency 'FacebookLogin', '~> 0.2.0'
  s.dependency 'FacebookShare', '~> 0.2.0'
  s.dependency 'Fabric', '~> 1.6.11'
  s.dependency 'TwitterKit', '~> 2.8.1'
  s.dependency 'Google/SignIn', '~> 3.0.3'
  s.dependency 'LinkedinSwift', '~> 1.7.4'

  s.source_files = "Socializin/**/*.{swift}"
  #s.resources = "Socializin/**/*.{png,jpeg,jpg,storyboard,xib}"
end
```

But the dependencies give me the following error

`[!] The 'Pods-socializinTest' target has transitive dependencies that include static binaries: (/Users/x/projects/x/Examples/socializinTest/Pods/Fabric/iOS/Fabric.framework, /Users/x/projects/x/Examples/socializinTest/Pods/Google/Frameworks/GGLCore.framework, and /Users/x/projects/x/Examples/socializinTest/Pods/Google/Frameworks/GGLSignIn.framework)`

Is there anyway to make sure it does work? All I want to do is create a pod that will make it easy to use all those services and being able to add more to it whenever needed.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you are still looking for a solution. 

This is what i did:

I put the Google SignIn framework under /Dependency/GoogleDependency

And i put the TwitterKit, TwitterCore and Fabric frameworks under /Dependency/TwitterDependency/

```
Pod::Spec.new do |s|
  s.platform     = :ios
  s.ios.deployment_target = '9.0'
  s.name         = "Socializin"
  s.version      = "0.0.1"
  s.summary      = "A short description of Socializin."
  s.requires_arc = true

  s.author       = {"MyName" => "MyMail"}
  s.homepage     = "http://EXAMPLE/Socializin"
  s.license      = { :type => "MIT", :file => "LICENSE" }
  s.source       = { :git => "", :tag => "#{s.version}"}

  s.framework    = "UIKit"
  s.dependency 'FacebookCore', '~> 0.2.0'
  s.dependency 'FacebookLogin', '~> 0.2.0'
  s.dependency 'FacebookShare', '~> 0.2.0'
  s.dependency 'LinkedinSwift', '~> 1.7.4'

  s.source_files = "Socializin/**/*.{swift}"
  #s.resources = "Socializin/**/*.{png,jpeg,jpg,storyboard,xib}"

  #----------------------------Sub Modules-----------------#
  s.subspec 'GoogleAuthentication' do |ss|
    ss.ios.deployment_target = '9.0'
    ss.source_files = 'Socializin/Dependency/GoogleDependency/**/*.{swift}'
    ss.resources = ['Socializin/Dependency/GoogleDependency/**/*.{xib,xcdatamodeld,bundle}']
    ss.vendored_frameworks = ['Socializin/Dependency/GoogleDependency/**/*.{framework}']
    ss.preserve_paths = ['Socializin/Dependency/GoogleDependency/**/*.{framework}']
    frameworkPaths = ''
    Dir.glob('Socializin/Dependency/GoogleDependency/**/*.{framework}') do |filename|
      filePath = Pathname.new(filename)
      newFilename = filePath.dirname
      if frameworkPaths != "" 
        frameworkPaths = "#{frameworkPaths} \"$(PODS_ROOT)/#{newFilename}\""
      else
        frameworkPaths = "\"$(PODS_ROOT)/#{newFilename}\""
      end
    end
    ss.xcconfig = { 
      'FRAMEWORK_SEARCH_PATHS' => frameworkPaths,
      'HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS' => '"$(PODS_ROOT)/Socializin/Dependency/GoogleDependency"', 
    }
    #Authentication
    # ss.dependency 'GoogleSignIn'
    ss.dependency 'GoogleToolboxForMac/NSDictionary+URLArguments'
    ss.dependency 'GoogleToolboxForMac/NSData+zlib'
  end

  s.subspec 'TwitterAuthentication' do |ss|
    ss.ios.deployment_target = '9.0'
    ss.source_files = 'Socializin/Dependency/TwitterDependency/**/*.{swift}'
    ss.resources = ['Socializin/Dependency/TwitterDependency/TwitterKit/iOS/TwitterKit.framework/*.{xib,xcdatamodeld,bundle}']
    ss.vendored_frameworks = ['Socializin/Dependency/TwitterDependency/**/*.{framework}']
    ss.preserve_paths = ['Socializin/Dependency/TwitterDependency/**/*.{framework}']
    frameworkPaths = ''
    Dir.glob('Socializin/Dependency/TwitterDependency/**/*.{framework}') do |filename|
      filePath = Pathname.new(filename)
      newFilename = filePath.dirname
      if frameworkPaths != "" 
        frameworkPaths = "#{frameworkPaths} \"$(PODS_ROOT)/#{newFilename}\""
      else
        frameworkPaths = "\"$(PODS_ROOT)/#{newFilename}\""
      end
    end
    ss.xcconfig = { 
      'FRAMEWORK_SEARCH_PATHS' => frameworkPaths,
      'HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS' => '"$(PODS_ROOT)/Socializin/Dependency/TwitterDependency"',
    }
    #Authentication
    # ss.dependency 'Fabric'
    # ss.dependency 'TwitterKit'
    # ss.dependency 'TwitterCore'
  end
end
```